# UIView subviews are not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create an UIView in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
CGRect inputTextViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 80);
UIView *inputTextView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:inputTextViewRect];
inputTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Then I create two subviews - one UIButton and one UITextView:

```
UITextView *inputTextField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 450, 230, 20)];
UIButton *sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(250, 450, 50, 20);
```

My problem is if I add my `inputTextField` and `sendButton` as subviews to main window - they will be visible and working. If I add them to my `UIView`:

```
[inputTextView addSubview:inputTextField];
[inputTextView addSubview:sendButton];
```

And then add this view to main window:

```
[self.window addSubview:inputTextView];
```

In this case i see only gray background of `inputTextView` and no subviews that were added before.
Could you please help me figure out whats wrong with it?

Comment: Actually the position should be set with corresponding to its superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `CGRectMake` call:

```
CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

x and y and are coordinates where you want to place the element over the super view, so you have the following, which is incorrect:

```
CGRect inputTextViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 80);
UITextView *inputTextField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 450, 230, 20)]; 
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(250, 450, 50, 20);
```

Try changing those to

```
CGRect inputTextViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
UITextView *inputTextField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 230, 20)];
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20);
```

After changing this you will be able to see UITextView and UIButton, then you make the x and y position changes according to your need.

Comment: Thank you, had to figure out this by myself. Subviews coordinates should be relative to parent view, not the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you add `inputTextField` subview of `inputTextView`, it will be placed at y position of 450 inside `inputTextView`. But that itself is of height 80 only.

So when you add that into `inputTextView`, make the origin y position to 30.

So, if you add to main view, it will be like

```
UITextView *inputTextField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 450, 230, 20)];
```

Else if you add it to `inputTextView`, then

```
UITextView *inputTextField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 230, 20)];
```